# Code isn't working as it was before (selenium java)

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

i had to add shampoo in the cart 
it was working fine 
but now its not 
their is no change in the code
now it scroll the page down and stop working
Below is my code

```
driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait (driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("logout-trigger")));
driver.findElement(By.id("search-trigger")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
driver.findElement(By.id("search")).sendKeys("Shampoo");
driver.findElement(By.id("search")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
driver.findElement(By.id("grid_quantity_1")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Add to cart"));
actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink);
actions.click();
actions.perform();
```

The web code is

```
<div class="grid-add-to-cart" ng-show="prod.currentPrice > 0" ng-mouseleave="hidegridViewToggle($index+1)">
  <a title="Add to cart" href="javascript:void(0)" ng-mouseover="showgridViewToggle($index+1)" ng-click="helperService.addToCart('grid_product',prod.productSizeId,$index+1,prod.itemsPerBox)">
    <i class="fa fa-shopping-bag faa-shake animated"></i>
  </a>
  <div class="grid-quantity-field" id="show_grid_input_div_1">
    <input ng-keypress="($event.which===13)?helperService.addToCart('grid_product',prod.productSizeId,$index+1,prod.itemsPerBox):helperService.keyCheck($event)" type="number" name="quantity" id="grid_quantity_1" data-ng-class="$even ? 'height_80' : ''" oninput="maxLengthCheck(this)" ng-model="prod.itemsPerBoxInput" maxlength="5" min="1" max="99999" ng-value="userType == 'distributor' ? 6: 1" title="Add Quantity" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-min ng-valid-max ng-valid-maxlength height_80 ng-touched" value="1" style="">
  </div>
</div>
```

What i am getting on eclipse

```
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:635)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:322)
```

Comment: Explain *stop working*. what exactly happens? if you have an exception post the stack trace as well.

Comment: It does not perform any action
as before i was able to add a product in cart
but now it scroll the page down and does not add the product in cart

Comment: From the html code of the link, we can know there must be a javascript function to response to the click event of the link.  In this case, you need to wait the browser to execute scripts tags on page completely to bind javascript function to click event,  otherwise, it will nothing happen after click on it.  you can add some wait/sleep before  actions.perform()  to see your issue is such case or not.

Comment: Did you change anything from the time it worked to now? Upgraded Selenium version? Updated your page version (different HTML)?

Comment: No nothing is changed

Comment: Please paste the error log here

Comment: In order to investigate the issue you need to provide us the complete error stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the `HTML` you have shared, you have the following :

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Add to cart"));
```

which seems to need some modification in the `xpath`. Can you try the following line of code instead:

```
WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Add to cart']"));
```

Comment: Thank You for your help
It worked when i restarted but again it stopped working

Comment: Update the Question with the exact entire error stack trace.

Comment: Updated with the response